# how do i call the amazon selling partner API from R?

Tags: r, httr, amazon-selling-partner-api

i am trying to retrieve data from the amazon sp api using the httr package.
what i did so far is:

(0) prerequisites

```
library(httr)
library(httr2)
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)
```

(1) defined data as:

```
data = list(
  grant_type = "refresh_token",
  refresh_token = "Atzr|...",
  client_id = "amzn1...",
  client_secret = "amzn1....")
```

to get (2) a 'access_token' value as POST request response from:

```
token_response = httr::POST(
  url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token",
  body = data) 

access_token = fromJSON(token_response)[["access_token"]]
```

i also (3) defined request params:

```
markentplace_endpoint = "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com"
marketplace_id = "A1PA6795UKMFR9"

request_params = list(
  "MarketplaceId" = marketplace_id, 
  "CreatedAfter" = as_date(Sys.Date()-30))
```

and (4) and an url string:

```
url = paste0(markentplace_endpoint, "/orders/v0/orders")
url$query = request_params
url = paste0(paste0(markentplace_endpoint, "/orders/v0/orders"), url_build(url))
```

to finally (5) make a GET request

```
httr::GET(
  url = paste0(paste0(markentplace_endpoint, "/orders/v0/orders"), url_build(url)), 
  add_headers(`x-amz-access-token` = access_token))
```

In the end, I'm already stuck at step 2, because I get the following response from my POST request:

```
Response [https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token]
  Date: 2024-01-07 12:13
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Size: 392 B
```

i was basically following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gp5kTI8I3pU tutorial and was trying to adapt to R/R Studio.

does anyone have more experience and is willing to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 400 response code typically means the request you are sending is malformed. By default the `httr::POST` function will encode the body as `multipart/form-data` ("multipart"). The amazon API specifically requires the data to be encoded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ("form"). So to get the proper response you would use

```
token_response <- httr::POST(
  url = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token",
  encode = "form",
  body = data)
```